# admission webhook can not catch the "update" operation

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks

I am working on a customized admission webhook, need to add additional labels to all the deployments, the label maybe like this: "test1: mylabels". I defined two operations in the webhook, CREATE and UPDATE. The create requests always received, but the update requests didnot work as expected. After create deployment, **only if I delete the customized label "test1: mylabels", I can receive the UPDATE request.** I did other tests like manually add more labels, update the annotations or update images tags,replicas, I **CANNOT** receive any update request.

The MutatingWebhookConfiguration definition:

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-03-24T05:42:13Z"
  generation: 44
  name: demo-webhook
  resourceVersion: "696021949"
  uid: a0bd5835-3393-4a68-8f06-196bf561036d
webhooks:
- admissionReviewVersions:
  - v1
  - v1beta1
  clientConfig:
    caBundle: LS0tLS1CRUdJ...
    url: https://9.x.x.x:9443/v1/mutate
  failurePolicy: Fail
  matchPolicy: Equivalent
  name: webhook-server.webhook-demo.svc
  namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      kubernetes.io/metadata.name: webhook-demo
  objectSelector:
    matchExpressions:
    - key: test1
      operator: DoesNotExist
  reinvocationPolicy: Never
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - '*'
    apiVersions:
    - '*'
    operations:
    - CREATE
    - UPDATE
    resources:
    - deployments
    scope: Namespaced
  sideEffects: None
  timeoutSeconds: 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Caused by my mistake. I used a objectSelector :(